# How to Write .htaccess that handles subdomains also to redirect to https:

Tags: .htaccess, centos7, vesta

I have this .htaccess rule

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
>
> RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

This covers the parent domain but not the subdomain.

My subdomain has the same public folder as of parent domain.

example.com is redirected to https://example.com

But subdomain.example.com is not redirected to https://subdomain.example.com

As I said above that both points to same public folder so I want the above rule to handle both.

But I don't want to write my domain or subdomain name in htaccess rule. It shall cover any domain and any subdomain

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `HTTP_HOST` header:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

So you get it from the request rather than using the server name for the virtual host. Also simplifying the regex since you’re not using the capture.

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto your subdomain folder
2. Create .htaccess file in this folder
3. and paste this code:

just copy and paste this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```